# Dehydrobromination of 3-bromo-3-cyclopentylhexane and number of possible alkene products

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, molecular-structure, isomers

I faced a question like this:

> The total number of alkene products possible from the dehydrobromination of 3-bromo-3-cyclopentylhexane is:

The answer is given 5. But I only found 3.

1. 3-cyclopentylhex-2-ene
2. 3-cyclopentylhex-3-ene
3. (hexan-3-ylidene)cyclopentane

I can't find the other 2. Any hint?

Comment: Stereoisomers are counted apparently. Both 1 and 2 have (*E*)- and (*Z*)-isomers.

Comment: I agree with Orthocresol, do consider stereoisomers,sometimes the question doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: solution re]

The structures (i) and (ii) have two isomers each,namely E and Z isomers.

For the structure (iii) there is a plane of symmetry (marked in the diagram) so it is not a geometrical isomer.

Thus Number of isomers=2 (of structure i) +2 (of structure        ii) + 1(of structure iii)= 5 isomers

Comment: Umm, plane of symmetry should not be considered here, as we are looking for geometrical isomerism. Instead you can say that two groups attached to the double bond are identical.

Comment: In fact, the molecule does *not* have a plane of symmetry there, since an ethyl residue (chain left-hand side) and a propyl residue (chain, right-hand side) are not identical. What you *should* be discussing are the identical substituents on the other side of the double bond.