# Number of products on dehydrobromination

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, carbocation, elimination, rearrangements

Question:

> The total number of alkene products possible from the dehydrobromination of 3-bromo-3-cyclopentylhexane using alcohol KOH is :

This question was asked here before but I am getting more products than those mentioned there

[Dehydrobromination of 3-bromo-3-cyclopentylhexane and number of possible alkene products](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/74992/dehydrobromination-of-3-bromo-3-cyclopentylhexane-and-number-of-possible-alkene)

My doubt is, why doesn't Hydride shift and ring expansion take place here? I would expect the Elimination reaction to be E1 as Br is a good leaving group and it is 3° halide. So there should be a carbocation intermediate on C3.

There is an alpha hydrogen in the cyclopentyl ring wrt this carbocation. Why won't hydride shift or ring expansion into cyclohexane (more stable ring) take place here?

Comment: The bromide is tertiary. There are no cations involved. There are five alkenes. There are stereoisomers as your link suggests.

Comment: Yes it is a 3° halide(fixed the typo). So are you suggesting that E2 would take place? Why wouldn't E1 take place?

Comment: With a strong base, such as KOH, present E2 predominates over E1. E2 is kinetically controlled and given sufficient time, the alkenes from an E1 will be equilibrated by the liberated HBr to a thermodynamic mixture of alkenes. The E2 mixture of alkenes is usually different from the E1 mixture.